# Trying to save user to mysql with uuid binary(16)

Tags: mysql, express

In Express/Mysql, I am trying to retrieve user by id. In Postman, I retrieve users and get data that looks like:

```
"id": {
            "type": "Buffer",
            "data": [
                99,
                98,
                48,
                99,
                52,
                97,
                100,
                48,
                45,
                52,
                52,
                56,
                102,
                45,
                52,
                57
            ]
        },
        "email":  "user3@gmail.com",
...
```

In SQL, when I retrieve users, I am getting ids like: "0x63623063346164302D343438662D3439", which I am unable to query by.

Here is the migration that creates the table:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('users', function(table) {
    table.binary('id', 16).primary();
    table.string('email').notNullable();
    table.string('username');
    table.string('password').notNullable();
    table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
    table.timestamp('last_login').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
  })
}

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('users');
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Adding the route info and the method for user creation, so I can get a little more guidance on how to apply the answer below.
the user registration route:

```
router.post("/", auth.optional, async (req, res, next) => {
  const {
    body: { user }
  } = req;
  console.log(
    "In post new user, this is the req received from Vue: ",
    req
  );

...

  const finalUser = await authHelpers.createUser(req, res);
  console.log("In creat user route, The finalUser is " + finalUser);

  res.json({ user: authHelpers.toAuthJSON(finalUser) });
});
```

createUser method:

```
async function createUser(req, res) {
  const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
  const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.user.password, salt);
  console.log('helpers.js assigning this value to hash: ', hash)
  let newUser = await User.query()
    .insert({
      id: uuid.v4(),
      email: req.body.user.email,
      password: hash,
      username: req.body.user.username,
      slug: slugify(req.body.user.username)
    });
  console.log("helper.js creating new User: ", newUser);
  return newUser;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the MySQL functions BIN_TO_UUID and UUID_TO_BIN.

BIN_TO_UUID - this function is used when you retrieve the binary column from the db

```
SELECT BIN_TO_UUID(userIdBinary) userIdString
```

UUID_TO_BIN - this function can be used to save binary data in the db, or in a WHERE clause (HOWEVER, it does not use indexes due to a MySQL bug - at least in MySQL 5.7!)

```
WHERE userId = UUID_TO_BIN('string_of_binary_userId')
```

MySQL 8 has built-in support for this:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html

Prior to MySQL 8, you can create the functions yourself.  Follow the instructions here, or search for this on stackoverflow.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/

Comment: so where do I use this? when I retrieve the value or when I save it to the db?

Comment: I updated the post, let me know if it's clearer now.

Comment: I am still not clear on where exactly to put the suggested code. I have added the route and method where the user is created.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I realize you are using express, i would suggest using the binary-uuid-ts npm package.  In the insert, you should convert the uuid to binary:

```
.insert({
  id: uuidToBinaryUUID(uuid.v4()),
  email: req.body.user.email,
  password: hash,
  username: req.body.user.username,
  slug: slugify(req.body.user.username)
});
```

You can convert the binary back to string in node via the binaryUUIDToUUID.  Alternatively, you can convert it back to string in MySQL (with the warning above about the MySQL bug with it not using indexes in the WHERE clause).

Comment: Trying this, but i can't get it to work.  uuidToBinaryUUID is not defined. Couldn't find binary-uuid-ts package so I tried to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/binary-uuid, which seemed to have the methods I needed. Tried to use knex.raw insert into users ('id'...) VALUES (UNHEX(UUID()),...) but that throws "knex.raw is not a function"

Comment: Here is the full insert attempt with knex.raw (to let mysql handle this vs doing it in js): let newUser = await knex.raw('INSERT INTO "users" (id, email, password, username, slug) VALUES (UNHEX(UUID()), req.body.user.email, hash, req.body.user.username, slugify(req.body.user.username))')

Comment: If you would like to use a MySQL function you can replace the UNHEX in your query with UUID_TO_BIN.  First create the function in your database as per:  https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/

Comment: OR you can use the node function:  VALUES (uuidToBinaryUUID(uuid()), where the uuid() is a node function (not MySQL)